# Outlook email is forwarding to an email address, but I want to change it to a different email. I can't

Tags: email, outlook, office365

The situation:

- Former executive director of company, director@company.com, has email forwarded to person1@company.com
- Current executive director, person2@company.com, wants this email forwarded to him.

The issue:

1. Company migrated to Office 365 prior to my IT company coming onboard
2. We don't have access to director@company.com
3. But it still forwards to person1@company.com (how?)
4. We do have admin access to Office 365.

What I did:

- I was able to get, from forwarded emails, to Outlook.com to reset the director@company.com password. I now have access to this mailbox.

The next problem:

- I don't receive any emails to this mailbox, which I am accessing via Outlook.com. I am able to send mail out, but I cannot receive it, because:
- Whatever is forwarding incoming emails is catching them before they reach me and forwarding them to person1@company.com
- When I respond to emails that director@company.com sends out, no replies are received at Outlook.com

How do I find out where this forwarding is controlled so I can change it? There are no email servers that we access or manage.

- Outlook.com forwarding shows nothing
- POP is turned off
- There are no connected accounts listed

And bonus question: Can I add director@company.com to come under the Office 365 @company.com umbrella? They share the same @company.com so how does that work?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: I do not see how this question is in anyway outside the parameters of this site. I can see how the title is misleading, but if you read the question, it more than satisfies the "questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment" criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the path of a message.
Check your MX records, if they are going directly to your 365 that means somewhere in 365 you have something in your mailflow that is causing that message to be redirected. Check the director account it has to be referenced somewhere in 365.

Login as the user and see if they have any rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have you logged into the Office 365 Admin portal and looked for the user account list? Since the company is using O365, if all the email accounts are set up through that (rather than directly in Outlook.com) then there should be a list of user accounts there, either completely standalone (in Office 365) or synced with an on-premises Active Directory structure if you have that. Forwards can be set up in accounts this way, as well as the other methods you checked already, and that's where you may find this one since you're not seeing it elsewhere.

I usually log into the O365 Admin portal via this URL: https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home. Once you have the correct administrator credentials, you should be able to access the list of Users (and other useful things).

Comment: Hello, yes, I have Admin rights for this company's Office 365 and director@company.com is not among the user accounts. This account is older than when they migrated over to Office 365 and was not included in the migration. Basically, it's orphaned.

I appreciate the help though.